# Getting a date format from your computer settings using Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I need a little help with this one. I need to get a date format from a local computer, which a code is being ran on. Which library do I use or how do I approach this mistery using python ? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "date format"? something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), i.e. a format *code*?

Comment: Yes, something like you referred to. I need to get info what kind of format it is. If it's %d%m%Y or %m%d%Y or %Y%m%d etc.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

one idea would be to set the appropriate [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) from the OS environment variables, then create a date/time string using [directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
%x    Locale’s appropriate date representation.
%X    Locale’s appropriate time representation.
```

and finally "reverse-engineer" the format using for example pandas' [datetime guesser](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx#L946):

```py
import os
import locale
from datetime import datetime
from pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing import guess_datetime_format

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, os.environ['LC_TIME'])

print(os.environ['LC_TIME'])
print(guess_datetime_format(datetime.now().strftime("%x %X")))

# on the machine I use at the moment that prints:
# de_DE.UTF-8
# %d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S
```